# pynamodb create Model based off existing Class object

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I am using pynamodb in a Python Flask project and am starting to build my model(s) to define the objects that will be used with tables.

The documentation says you define a model as follows:

```
from pynamodb.models import Model
from pynamodb.attributes import UnicodeAttribute

    class UserModel(Model):
        """
        A DynamoDB User
        """
        class Meta:
            table_name = "dynamodb-user"
        email = UnicodeAttribute(null=True)
        first_name = UnicodeAttribute(range_key=True)
        last_name = UnicodeAttribute(hash_key=True)
```

However I already have an existing class in another module, that I've already defined, see below:

```
class ActivityTask:
    def __init__(self,task_name, sequence_order):
        self.taskid = uuid.uuid4()
        self.taskcreated = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.taskname = task_name
        self.sequenceorder = sequence_order
```

Is there a way for me to somehow "port" my existing ActivityTask class object so that I can use it as a model? As it already matches the schema for the DynamoDB table in question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class I made to automatically generate a Pynamodb Model from a Marshmellow class :

```
class PynamodbModel:
def __init__(self, base_object):
    self.base_object = base_object

    attributes = self.make_attributes(self.base_object.schema)

    meta_attr = {"table_name" : self.base_object.__name__}

    attributes['Meta'] = type("Meta", (), meta_attr)

    self.table : Model = type("Table", (Model,), attributes)

def convert_attr(self, attr):
    if type(attr) == Nested:
        atttr = attr.inner.nested

def make_attributes(self, schema_obj):
    attributes = {}

    for name, elem in schema_obj._declared_fields.items():
        if name == 'id':
            attributes[name] = attibute_conversion[type(elem)](hash_key=True)
        elif type(elem) == List:
            if type(elem.inner) == Nested:
                attributes[name] = attibute_conversion[type(elem)](of=self.make_nested_attr(elem.inner.nested))
            else:
                attributes[name] = attibute_conversion[type(elem)]()

        elif type(elem) == Nested:
            attributes[name] = self.make_nested_attr(elem.nested)

        else:
            attributes[name] = attibute_conversion[type(elem)]()

    return attributes

def make_nested_attr(self, nested_schema):

    attributes = self.make_attributes(nested_schema)

    return type(nested_schema.__class__.__name__, (MapAttribute,), attributes)
```

[Go here to see the full example !](https://gist.github.com/Vaunorage/2b53f91b9b6315ae87442781e71ae581)

I basically just iterate over the Marshmellow Schema attributes and assign the correspondant Pynamodb attributes. Hope it help !